# Im trying to import geopandas but its not importing on vscode

Tags: python, geopandas

```sh
import geopandas 
File "c:/Users/awips/OneDrive/Desktop/Wxsky.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
File "C:\Users\awips\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
File "C:\Users\awips\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 36, in <module>      
    from cartopy._crs import CRS, Geodetic, Globe, PROJ4_VERSION
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _crs: The specified module could not be found.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\awips\anaconda3\envs\myenv: 
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
geopandas                 0.9.0                      py_1
geopandas-base            0.9.0                      py_1
(myenv) PS C:\Users\awips>
```

Comment: are you sure that you have installed that library on your enviorment? or are you sure that you are using the enviorment in VSCode?

Comment: I reformatted your question - please use [code formatting](/help/formatting) rather than a quote block to include error logs, data, and code. Make sure that geopandas can be imported *outside* vscode - otherwise it's not a vscode issue it's just an issue with your installation. Additionally, make sure that all packages in your conda environment are built with the same channel (e.g. "default" or "conda-forge", not mixed). Try `conda create -n geopandas -c conda-forge geopandas` and see if that helps.